# Moved a file with mv but now I can't find it

Tags: command-line, mv

It seems I made a mistake in the command. It still executed a move, but now I can't find the file.

My command was this:

```
mv /tank/incoming/myfile.mov \(2017\)/ /tank/myfiles/
```

The command was executed, which took a while, and the feedback was:

```
mv: cannot stat '(2017)/': No such file or directory
```

So, where is my file?

Is it still existing? Is there a way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter `\(2017\)/` has been ignored, as stated by the error message, and the file has been moved to `/tank/myfiles/`.

Comment: Yes, right.. Nautilus was not showing the file for some reason, but after refreshing I see it. Thank you!